# Lombok @Wither, @Value, @NoArgsConstructor, @AllArgsConstructor do not work together

Tags: java, lombok

I am writing a simple model as below. I can see the wither function in intellij structure view. but compiler complains about "variable field1 might not have been initialized"

```
@Wither
@Value
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class MyModel {
    String field1;
    String field2;
}
```

If I initialize the fields, I donot see wither functions anymore. What could be happening here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As from the [documentation](https://projectlombok.org/features/Value):

`@Value` is the immutable variant of `@Data`; all fields are made private and final by default, and setters are not generated.

---

So `String field1` becomes `final String field1`.

Since you are also using `@NoArgsConstructor` Java compiler complains that "variable field1 might not have been initialized", which is true, since somewhere in the code you can do

```
MyModel model = new MyModel();
```

and since the constructor does not initialize any fields, Java complains.

From [Final (Java)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_(Java)#Final_variables) wiki:

A final variable can only be initialized once, either via an initializer or an assignment statement. It does not need to be initialized at the point of declaration: this is called a "blank final" variable. A blank final instance variable of a class must be definitely assigned in every constructor of the class in which it is declared; similarly, a blank final static variable must be definitely assigned in a static initializer of the class in which it is declared; otherwise, a compile-time error occurs in both cases.

---

And this is exactly what happens in your case.

Comment: I guess, lombok should support this use-case.

Comment: @PrabhatRanjan How? An immutable object must have all field immutable, i.e., assigned during construction. So `@Value` and `@NoArgsConstructor` are mutually exclusive (except for classes having no fields). The best what could be done, is a specialized error message for this combo.

Comment: @maaartinus I was thinking of special implementation :
public MyModel() {
this(null, null)
}

Comment: @PrabhatRanjan But isn't such a null-only immutable object useless most of the time? When strings are involved, you prefer `""` instead, similarly for collections... all in all, there'll be maybe 10 uses of each  variant of this feature around the world. ;)

Comment: Sometimes the default constructor must be available for reflection, like in JPA spec, but you want the object immutable (JPA accesses fields through reflection)